Convexity of point-to-set mapping
For any $p\in[0,1]$ and a given $W\in\mathbb{R}$, I define the set $S(p)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ as
$$S(p)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \vert x+py+(1-p)z \leq W\}.$$
Can I say that the mapping $S:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is convex, in the sense that if $(x_1,y_1,z_1)\in S(p_1)$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2)\in S(p_2)$ then for any $\lambda \in (0,1)$, one has
$$\lambda (x_1,y_1,z_1) + (1-\lambda) (x_2,y_2,z_2)\in S(\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2)?$$
Any pointers much appreciated. I tried the brutal way and I don't get anywhere.

What is your try

I define $(x_\lambda,y_\lambda,z_\lambda)=\lambda (x_1,y_1,z_1) + (1-\lambda) (x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $p_\lambda=\lambda p_1 + (1-\lambda) p_2$ and I check whether $x_\lambda$ is in $S(p_\lambda)$. I just get lots of terms and it does not jump at me that it works. I think it is actually not convex.

Isn't $S(p)$ just the half-space which is limite by the Euclidean plane associted to the strict equality in the equation? Then, it should be convex.

$S(p)$ is convex, yes. Is this what you mean? I am asking about the mapping from $p$ to $S(p)$.

Let $p_1=0, p_2=1$, $W = 0, \lambda = 0.5$,
$$\begin{align*}
(x_1,y_1,z_1) &= (0,2,0) \in S(p_1) \\
(x_2,y_2,z_2) &= (0,0,2) \in S(p_2)
\end{align*}$$
$$S(\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2)=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3 \vert x+0.5y+0.5z \leq 0\}$$
$$\lambda (x_1,y_1,z_1) + (1-\lambda) (x_2,y_2,z_2)
=(0,1,1)\notin S(\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2)$$
